# How to save a plot from WolframCloud in the best quality?

Tags: plotting, image, wolfram-cloud

I am using wolframcloud.com for generating a plot, but when I save it by right clicking and following "Save image as..." the plot gets saved with low quality (blurred). Is there a better way of saving plots  from wolframcloud to my  laptop with better quality?

Answer (score 3):

```
Unprotect[$ImageResolution]; 
$ImageResolution = 120 ;
Export[
    CloudObject@"Test.PNG",
    Plot[
        AiryAi[x]
        , {x, -10, 10}
        , PlotTheme->{"Scientific", "LargeLabels"}
        , PlotStyle -> DropShadowing[]
        , MaxRecursion->5
        , ImageSize->900
        , Prolog-> Inset[ResourceFunction["DropShadow"][ChemicalData["Caffeine", "StructureDiagram"]]]
    ]
    ,"PNG"
]
```

[image]